# Change Cordova preferences based on iOS version

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

This is my function that gets the iOS version from my device:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
var deviceVersion = device.version;
console.log(deviceVersion);}
```

I need a function that each time the iOS version is lower or equals to 10.5 the value of `<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />`needs to be true, if iOS version is 11 or higher needs to be false.

[false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9udNr.jpg)

[true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asiB4.jpg)

I have this variable 'deviceVersion' saved into a file named utils.js but my preferences values are into a file config.xml. How can I change a value into an xml file based on a variable on javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<if>
    <conditions>
        <condition var="ios-CFBundleVersion" operator="&gt;" >11.0.0</condition>
    </conditions>

    <statements>
        <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true"/>
    </statements>
</if>

<else>
    <statements>
        <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
    </statements>
</else>
```

Ended up doing this, and worked perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, May be crazy

```
let versionStr = "\(deviceVersion)"
let float = versionStr.floatValue

if float > 11.0
{
   // do your stuff
}
else
{
   // Handle earlier Versions
}
```